# Update or Insert New Data from a Staging table to Another Table Conditionally and in Bulk

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers, mariadb

I have two tables: 1.) **Table A:** a staging table for bank accounts and 2.) **Table B:** a primary table for bank accounts. Each day, Table A (the staging table) is cleared and updated with the most up-to-date data.

What is the best way to find the data that has changed in Table A and update Table B with each of the rows in bulk with bank accounts that has new or changed data?

I tried creating a stored procedure that runs on a daily basis that does the following:

1. Searches for new bank accounts. To do this, I query for bank account numbers in Table A that don't exist in Table B.
2. Finds rows in Table B with matching bank account numbers in Table A, but different data. However, I couldn't get this part of the query to work. How do I compare the data between two tables?

From there, I need to UPDATE Table B with rows that have changed and INSERT net new rows using IF / ELSE statements (Also struggled to get this to work).

I have the feeling I'm overcomplicating this issue, so I'm hoping somebody may have a different way to tackle this issue than a stored procedure that's run daily. For example, would a trigger in Table A make more sense?

Comment: Have a look at the INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax